# Netscape bookmark file generator

Tags: error-handling, rust

I started to learn Rust some time ago and I wonder if there is some way to write Rust code that is both concise and safe — in particular, avoiding `unwrap()`, casting functions and `try!()`.

Let's see an example. I wrote a software to generate random bookmarks and save them to a file, both in Rust and Haskell to compare.

First, I'll show you the Haskell version:

> ```
> import Control.Monad (liftM2, replicateM)
> import System.Environment (getArgs)
> import System.Random (newStdGen, randomRs)
>
> main :: IO ()
> main = do
>     args <- getArgs
>     file <- generateFile args
>     case file of
>         Just (outputFile, fileContent) -> writeFile outputFile fileContent
>         Nothing -> putStrLn "Usage: ./GenBookmarks outputfile.html [count]"
>
> generateFile :: [String] -> IO (Maybe (String, String))
> generateFile [outputFile, count] = do
>     fileContent <- generateFileContent $ read count
>     return $ Just (outputFile, fileContent)
> generateFile [outputFile] = generateFile [outputFile, "10"]
> generateFile _ = return Nothing
>
> generateFileContent :: Int -> IO String
> generateFileContent count = do
>     bookmarks <- generateBookmarks count
>     let fileLines =
>             [ "<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>"
>             , "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">"
>             , "<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>"
>             , "<H1>Menu des marque-pages</H1>"
>             , "<DL><p>"
>             ]
>             ++ bookmarks
>     return $ unlines fileLines
>
> generateBookmarks :: Int -> IO [String]
> generateBookmarks count =
>     liftM2 (++) (replicateM count generateDirectory) (replicateM (count * 4) generateBookmark)
>     where generateDirectory = do
>                 directoryName <- generateName
>                 return $ "<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=\"1438910135\" LAST_MODIFIED=\"1438910135\">" ++ directoryName ++ "</H3>"
>           generateBookmark = do
>                 bookmarkName <- generateName
>                 return $ "<DL><p>\n<DT><A HREF=\"https://" ++ bookmarkName ++ ".com/\">" ++ bookmarkName ++ "</a>\n</DL><p>"
>
> generateName :: IO String
> generateName = do
>     g <- newStdGen
>     return $ take 10 $ randomRs ('a', 'z') g
> ```

Here is the Rust version:

```
extern crate rand;

use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

use rand::Rng;

fn options() -> Option<(String, i32)> {
    match env::args().count() {
        2 => Some ((env::args().nth(1).unwrap(), 10)),
        3 => Some (
            (
                env::args().nth(1).unwrap(),
                env::args().nth(2).unwrap().parse().unwrap(),
            )
        ),
        _ => None,
    }
}

fn generate_name() -> String {
    rand::thread_rng().gen_ascii_chars().take(10).collect()
}

fn write_data(file: &mut File, count: i32) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    for _ in 1..count {
        let directory_name = generate_name();
        let directory = "<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=\"1438910135\" LAST_MODIFIED=\"1438910135\">".to_string() + &directory_name + "</H3>";
        try!(file.write(directory.as_bytes()));
        try!(file.write(b"\n"));
    }
    for _ in 1..count * 4 {
        let bookmark_name = generate_name();
        let bookmark = "<DL><p>\n<DT><A HREF=\"https://".to_string() + &bookmark_name + ".com/\">" + &bookmark_name + "</a>\n</DL><p>";
        try!(file.write(bookmark.as_bytes()));
        try!(file.write(b"\n"));
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn generate_file(outputfile: String, count: i32) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let data = vec![
        "<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>",
        "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">",
        "<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>",
        "<H1>Menu des marque-pages</H1>",
        "<DL><p>",
    ];
    let mut file = try!(File::create(outputfile));
    for line in data {
        try!(file.write(line.as_bytes()));
        try!(file.write(b"\n"));
    }
    try!(write_data(&mut file, count));
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    match options() {
        Some ((outputfile, count)) => {
            match generate_file(outputfile, count) {
                Ok(()) => (),
                Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
            }
        },
        None => println!("Usage: ./GenBookmarks outputfile.html [count]"),
    }
}
```

There is some parts of the Rust code that I feel are not good.
The `options()` function looks really bad and unsafe (and it is unsafe for parsing the number). The Haskell version use pattern matching on the program arguments (and is unsafe on parsing the number too, but this is not the point), but I didn't find a way to do something similar in Rust. In Rust, pattern matching against an array is unsafe by now.

Moreover, all the file writing (with all these `try!`) looks bad. Is there a better way of doing this?

Finally, having to use `to_string()`, `as_bytes()` and `b"some text"` is cumbersome. Is it possible to avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall, your code seems pretty reasonable. Let's look at your specific questions:

> The `options()` function looks really bad and unsafe

Let's get a piece of terminology out of the way: in Rust, the word
"unsafe" has a **very specific meaning** — memory unsafety. This code
has no memory safety issues.

It does have some ugliness though, mostly around the use of
`unwrap`. `unwrap` will crash the program if it is `None`, so it's
much nicer to avoid that when possible. Instead of checking the length
and then trusting that values are there, we can just pull some values
off the iterator and then pattern match on the results.

`Option` has methods like `map` and `and_then`, which correspond to option monad methods you may already be familiar with from Haskell. We use `unwrap_or` at the end to give a default value when the count is `None`, but this will never cause a panic.

The better solution would be to use a third party library for command
line argument parsing, but this will do for a quick solution.

> file writing (with all these `try!`) looks bad.

This is true, but does highlight the possible failures much more than
a language like C or C++ might. Unfortunately, Rust does not have the
monadic `do` syntax that can be used to clean this up in Haskell,
`try!` is it for the moment.

> to_string(), as_bytes() and b"some text" is cumbersome.

Agreed. To solve this, I'd suggest using the `write!` and `writeln!`
macros. These combine formatting strings and writing them to a given
formatter.

#### Other changes

- There's no reason to support a negative number of lines; use an unsigned value.
- There's no reason to tie the inner function to a `File`; any type that implements `Write` will do.
- Use the type alias for `io::Result` to avoid redundancy
- There's no reason to take a `String` argument; string slices (`&str`) are more flexible.
- There's no reason to create an allocated vector; an array on the stack is more efficient.

#### Final code

```
extern crate rand;

use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, Write};

use rand::Rng;

fn options() -> Option<(String, u32)> {
    let mut args = env::args();
    args.next(); // Skip the program argument

    match (args.next(), args.next()) {
        (Some(file), count) => {
            let count = count.and_then(|c| c.parse().ok()).unwrap_or(10);
            Some((file, count))
        },
        _ => None,
    }
}

fn generate_name() -> String {
    rand::thread_rng().gen_ascii_chars().take(10).collect()
}

fn write_data<W>(mut out: W, count: u32) -> io::Result<()>
    where W: io::Write
{
    for _ in 1..count {
        try!(write!(out, "<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=\"1438910135\" LAST_MODIFIED=\"1438910135\">{}</H3>", generate_name()));
    }
    for _ in 1..count * 4 {
        try!(write!(out, "<DL><p>\n<DT><A HREF=\"https://{0}.com/\">{0}</a>\n</DL><p>\n", generate_name()));
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn generate_file(outputfile: &str, count: u32) -> io::Result<()> {
    let data = [
        "<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>",
        "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">",
        "<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>",
        "<H1>Menu des marque-pages</H1>",
        "<DL><p>",
    ];
    let mut file = try!(File::create(outputfile));
    for line in &data {
        try!(writeln!(file, "{}", line));
    }
    try!(write_data(file, count));
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    match options() {
        Some((outputfile, count)) => {
            match generate_file(&outputfile, count) {
                Ok(()) => (),
                Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
            }
        },
        None => println!("Usage: ./GenBookmarks outputfile.html [count]"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's face it, what you *really* want is to know how to write your Haskell code in Rust. You can do a far more direct translation than you've shown.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    file <- generateFile args
```

is just

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().skip(1).collect();
    let file = generate_file(&args);
```

You have to explicitly `skip` the first argument and `collect` the rest, but it's not too different.

```
case file of
    Just (outputFile, fileContent) -> writeFile outputFile fileContent
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Usage: ./GenBookmarks outputfile.html [count]"
```

is more complex. One has to do all of:

```
match file {
    Some((output_file, file_content)) => File::create(output_file).unwrap().write_all(file_content.as_bytes()).unwrap(),
    None => println!("Usage: ./GenBookmarks outputfile.html [count]")
}
```

since Rust doesn't like skipping steps like opening files. Rust also won't implicitly panic in these cases, like Haskell does.

The next function is more tricky:

```
generateFile :: [String] -> IO (Maybe (String, String))
generateFile [outputFile, count] = do
    fileContent <- generateFileContent $ read count
    return $ Just (outputFile, fileContent)
generateFile [outputFile] = generateFile [outputFile, "10"]
generateFile _ = return Nothing
```

However, Rust does have unstable slice patterns, which you can enable on the unstable compilers with

```
#![feature(slice_patterns)]
```

Then you can do

```
fn generate_file(args: &[String]) -> Option<(String, String)> {
    match args {
        [ref output_file, ref count] => {
            let file_content = generate_file_content(count.parse().unwrap());
            Some((output_file.clone(), file_content))
        },
        [ref output_file] => {
            let val = output_file.clone();
            generate_file(&[val, "10".into()])
        },
        _ => None
    }
}
```

Sadly, there's no way to take by value here, so when recursing you need to require a `String` from your `&str` by doing

```
let val = output_file.clone();
generate_file(&[val, "10".into()])
```

Thus it's not so pretty in that regard.

The next function is *almost* direct:

```
generateFileContent :: Int -> IO String
generateFileContent count = do
    bookmarks <- generateBookmarks count
    let fileLines =
            [ "<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>"
            , "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">"
            , "<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>"
            , "<H1>Menu des marque-pages</H1>"
            , "<DL><p>"
            ]
            ++ bookmarks
    return $ unlines fileLines
```

goes to

```
fn generate_file_content(count: i32) -> String {
    let bookmarks = generate_bookmarks(count);
    let mut file_lines = vec![
        "<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>".into(),
        "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">".into(),
        "<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>".into(),
        "<H1>Menu des marque-pages</H1>".into(),
        "<DL><p>".into()
    ];
    file_lines.extend(bookmarks);
    file_lines.join("\n")
}
```

You need to do `.extend` as a second statement, but otherwise it's equivalent.

The next function is actually three:

```
generateBookmarks :: Int -> IO [String]
generateBookmarks count =
    liftM2 (++) (replicateM count generateDirectory) (replicateM (count * 4) generateBookmark)
    where generateDirectory = do
                directoryName <- generateName
                return $ "<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=\"1438910135\" LAST_MODIFIED=\"1438910135\">" ++ directoryName ++ "</H3>"
          generateBookmark = do
                bookmarkName <- generateName
                return $ "<DL><p>\n<DT><A HREF=\"https://" ++ bookmarkName ++ ".com/\">" ++ bookmarkName ++ "</a>\n</DL><p>"
```

Rust does have inline functions, but if you have them trailing you do need to explicitly `return`. Further, the expected way to do `replicateM count func` is `(0..count).map(|_| func()).collect()`, which is nowhere near as pretty.

```
fn generate_bookmarks(count: i32) -> Vec<String> {
    return (0..count).map(|_| generate_directory()).chain((0..count * 4).map(|_| generate_bookmark())).collect();
    fn generate_directory() -> String {
        let directory_name = generate_name();
        format!("<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=\"1438910135\" LAST_MODIFIED=\"1438910135\">{}</H3>", directory_name)
    }
    fn generate_bookmark() -> String {
        let bookmark_name = generate_name();
        format!("<DL><p>\n<DT><A HREF=\"https://{0}.com/\">{0}</a>\n</DL><p>", bookmark_name)
    }
}
```

One more function to go:

```
generateName :: IO String
generateName = do
    g <- newStdGen
    return $ take 10 $ randomRs ('a', 'z') g
```

Rust doesn't have a `randomRs` equivalent, so you again need to `replicateM` it. Further, chars aren't ranges in themselves, so a bit of casting is needed:

```
fn generate_name() -> String {
    let mut g = rand::thread_rng();
    (0..10).map(|_| g.gen_range('a' as u8, 'z' as u8 + 1) as char).collect()
}
```

There you go. That's how to write Haskell in Rust.

---

Well, let's try and write it a little nicer, eh?

First, a real argument parser is a good idea. I like Docopt, because it's so simple that it's normally *easier* than a hacky manual parse:

```
const USAGE: &'static str = "Usage: ./GenBookmarks <output-file> [<count>]";

#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct Args {
    arg_output_file: String,
    arg_count: Option<i64>
}

fn main() {
    let args = Docopt::new(USAGE).and_then(|d| d.decode());
    let args: Args = args.unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit());

    let file = File::create(args.arg_output_file);
    let count = args.arg_count.unwrap_or(10);

    ... // All parsed and ready to go
}
```

Note that I upped `arg_count` to an `i64` - there's little reason to use a small type here.

Before I continue, let's mention your "parser" first:

```
fn options() -> Option<(String, i32)> {
    match env::args().count() {
        2 => Some ((env::args().nth(1).unwrap(), 10)),
        3 => Some (
            (
                env::args().nth(1).unwrap(),
                env::args().nth(2).unwrap().parse().unwrap(),
            )
        ),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

The `unwrap`s here are a bit ugly. You can avoid this with a special technique of mine:

```
fn options() -> Option<(String, i32)> {
    let mut args = env::args();
    match (args.next(), args.next(), args.next()) {
        (Some(file_name), Some(count), None) =>
            count.parse().map(|i| (file_name, i)),
        (Some(file_name), None, _) => Some((file_name, 10)),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

This is different to Shepmaster's version because you explicitly check for `None` (only check *once*, though, as there's no guarantee that it will continue returning `None`). This means the length is exact, wheras Shepmaster's will accept any number of extra ignored arguments.

I suppose the next thing to do is delegate to some proper routine and handle resulting errors:

```
if let Err(e) = file.and_then(|mut f| write_random(&mut f, count)) {
    println!("Error opening file: {}", e);
    std::process::exit(1);
}
```

This is different to your

```
match generate_file(outputfile, count) {
    Ok(()) => (),
    Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
}
```

in that you don't care about the `Ok` branch, so `if let` avoids mentioning it.

You'd want to make `write` generic over writers, and start it like

```
const HEADER: &'static [u8] = b"\
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Menu des marque-pages</H1>
<DL><p>
";

fn write_random<W: Write>(mut out: W, count: i32) -> io::Result<()> {
    try!(out.write_all(HEADER));
    .. // Write rest
}
```

Writing the whole thing at once is much easier than the loop you tried.

I would complete this function with a few loops and a closure:

```
fn write_random<W: Write>(out: &mut W, count: i32) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut gen = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut generate_name = || -> String { gen.gen_ascii_chars().take(10).collect() };

    try!(write!(out, "{}", HEADER));

    for _ in 0..count {
        try!(writeln!(out,
            "<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=\"1438910135\" LAST_MODIFIED=\"1438910135\">{}</H3>",
            generate_name()
        ));
    }
    for _ in 0..count * 4 {
        try!(writeln!(out,
            "<DL><p>\n<DT><A HREF=\"https://{0}.com/\">{0}</a>\n</DL><p>",
            generate_name()
        ));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This is very similar to your version, except the `writeln!` macro dealt with formatting for me in a simple way. I also wrapped my lines, which is important for readability.

Note that I used `0..`, not `1..`. Using `1..` skips the first index.

Here's the full code:

```
extern crate docopt;
extern crate rand;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, Write};

use docopt::Docopt;
use rand::Rng;

const USAGE: &'static str = "Usage: ./GenBookmarks <output-file> [<count>]";

#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct Args {
    arg_output_file: String,
    arg_count: Option<i32>
}

const HEADER: &'static [u8] = b"\
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Menu des marque-pages</H1>
<DL><p>
";

fn write_random<W: Write>(out: &mut W, count: i32) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut gen = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut generate_name = || -> String { gen.gen_ascii_chars().take(10).collect() };

    try!(out.write_all(HEADER));

    for _ in 0..count {
        try!(writeln!(out,
            "<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=\"1438910135\" LAST_MODIFIED=\"1438910135\">{}</H3>",
            generate_name()
        ));
    }
    for _ in 0..count * 4 {
        try!(writeln!(out,
            "<DL><p>\n<DT><A HREF=\"https://{0}.com/\">{0}</a>\n</DL><p>",
            generate_name()
        ));
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let args = Docopt::new(USAGE).and_then(|d| d.decode());
    let args: Args = args.unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit());

    let file = File::create(args.arg_output_file);
    let count = args.arg_count.unwrap_or(10);

    if let Err(e) = file.and_then(|mut f| write_random(&mut f, count)) {
        println!("Error opening file: {}", e);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

You might notice that this actually takes noticably less text than the Haskell version (and the same number of significant lines), despite handling several error cases that the Haskell doesn't. This is partially due to the use of `Docopt` - using libraries is a good thing and shouldn't be avoided just because something's a quick job.

It also requires much less allocation, in that only the file and `generate_name` actually allocate! (Docopt *might* allocate, but it is only run once, so it doesn't matter.) Thus, whereas the Haskell code takes linear memory space, Rust takes constant space and somewhat less time.

Comment: +1 for "using libraries is a good thing". The Rust package ecosystem is pretty great. I haven't used the equivalent for Haskell, but what little I've heard wasn't a glowing recommendation.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks. I wish I could accept both answers.